Microsoft Clarity few sessions are disabled. How to fix it?
For user few sessions are able to record same user few time it shows as disabled.

Is there any setup issue?
Expected to record all the sessions from the users. What changes need to be made in settings?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Microsoft Clarity is a web service. As such, questions regarding it are off topic on this site. You should probably begin by contacting support for this service, but once you've done some more research regarding this, you may consider making a post on our Web Apps sister site.

Thank you for response contacting to support service. Few sessions unable to play where it is showing as disable icon.
Thanks you for your time for looking into it.
